# sms using clickatell, code not working

Tags: vb.net, sms, clickatell

I have signed up for clickatell service to send sms.  They have given me the following code for vb.net and said they do not know if this is right or wrong.

```
Dim client As WebClient = New WebClient
' Add a user agent header in case the requested URI contains a query.
client.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)")
client.QueryString.Add("user", "myusername")
client.QueryString.Add("password", "mypwd")
client.QueryString.Add("api_id", "myid")
client.QueryString.Add("to", "009232XXXXXXX")
client.QueryString.Add("text", "This is an example message using my vb.net code")
Dim baseurl As String = "http://api.clickatell.com/http/sendmsg"
Dim data As Stream = client.OpenRead(baseurl)
Dim reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(data)
Dim s As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
data.Close()
reader.Close()
Return
```

I tried the code, it did not give any error but sms was not received too.
Please help.

Comment: Except for the `api_id` and the `to` number that has the example values in, I can't see a problem with your code. What response did you get back from the API call?

Comment: examine the value of `s` - what does it contain?

Answer (score 0):

Your destination mobile number also should not have the leading zero's.

If you use the leading zero's, then the API will return this error: ERR: 105, Invalid Destination Address

You really need to log the API responses, otherwise you do not know if the gateway accepted your message.